# CSS variables in complex properties

Tags: css

Let's say I have a `box-shadow` property:

`box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 #ccc;`

What if I want to make a variable from `#ccc`? In SCSS I could do something like this:

```
$grey: #ccc;

.element {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 $grey;
}
```

But it doesn't work with native CSS variables. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: What have you *actually* tried?  We don't care what your Sass looks like because that's clearly not what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Variables is an experimental feature and is not currently supported everywhere (not IE support, Edge is in consideration, Firefox and Chrome - latest versions are OK). More info about it here: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables

```
// declaring a variable
.element {
  --variable: #ccc;
}
// using a variable
.other-element {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px var(--variable);
}
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: I think it is important to mention that it won't work in Edge/IE and Chrome.

Comment: @LGSon yes, I just provided an answer + link for more information that should have all the information about compatibility, but thank you for clarification :). I really though that it's kinda obvious that css variables is an experimental feature not supported by all the browsers.

Comment: As the OP asked why it was not working it is obviously not, and the link is good, though as Edge/IE/Chrome has a significant market share I think a special note is appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, He didnt provide us with the code he tried, so I assumed he didnt know ho to write it. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks again :).

Answer (score 0):

Guys I know it's a fresh feature, but you can't call it experimental since it's already landed in the stable version of Chrome.

As for my case, I found a solution. I can reuse that colour in another variable, and only then use it in an actual property. Here is an example:

```
:root {
    --focus-input-color: #6db3fd;
    --box-shadow-focus: 3px 3px 0 var(--focus-input-color),
                        -3px -3px 0 var(--focus-input-color),
                        -3px 3px 0 var(--focus-input-color),
                        3px -3px 0 var(--focus-input-color);
}
.element {
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-focus);
}
```

I don't know why this works and why it doesn't work when I use `--box-shadow-focus` directly in a property, but that's how it is in Chrome 49.

Comment: Being an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) doesn't mean it won't work in some or all browsers.